# Why hibernate delete operation does not work?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a basic Spring MVC project with the classic dao design for the classes User and Task. I'm using the Hibernate OpenSessionInView Filter pattern for the webapp; but, my `UserService` is not working properly, in fact its delete operation. The thing is, i have a simple unit test for this method, and it seems to work fine because when i run it, everything is ok, but when i test via the webapp, like this: `curl -X DELETE "http://myhost:port/users/someUserId"`, the delete operation does not work at all, because the object persist once it was invoked.

Here is part of my `UserService`:

```
@Override
public <T> User get(String key, T value) {
    User u = new User();

    switch (key) {
    case "id":
        u = (User) session.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, (Serializable) value);
        break;
    case "email":
        u = (User) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.email = :email").setParameter("email", value.toString()).uniqueResult();
        break;
    case "username":
        u = (User) session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User u where u.username = :username").setString("username", (String) value).uniqueResult();
        break;
    }
    if (u != null ) Hibernate.initialize(u.getTasks());
    return u;
}

@Override
public void delete(Integer userId) {
    session.getCurrentSession().delete(get("id",userId));
}
```

and `UserController`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteMemeber(@PathVariable Integer id) {

    userService.delete(id);

    return "redirect:/";

}
```

and the unit test for the `UserService` delete:

```
@Test
public void testUserDeleteService() {
    List<User> preUsers = userService.findAll();
    User userToDelete = userService.findById(3);

    userService.delete(3);

    List<User>postUsers = userService.findAll();

    assertNotEquals(preUsers, postUsers);
    assertEquals(preUsers.size() - 1, postUsers.size());
    assertFalse(userService.findAll().contains(userToDelete));
    assertNull(userService.findById(3));
}
```

Any ideas for why this is happening?

When the delete method is called, this is the logging:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, user0_.email as email2_1_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na3_1_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_1_0_, user0_.password as password5_1_0_, user0_.role as role6_1_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled7_1_0_, user0_.username as username8_1_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, user0_.email as email2_1_0_, user0_.first_name as first_na3_1_0_, user0_.last_name as last_nam4_1_0_, user0_.password as password5_1_0_, user0_.role as role6_1_0_, user0_.enabled as enabled7_1_0_, user0_.username as username8_1_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: select tasks0_.user_id as user_id6_1_0_, tasks0_.id as id1_0_0_, tasks0_.id as id1_0_1_, tasks0_.created_on as created_2_0_1_, tasks0_.deadline as deadline3_0_1_, tasks0_.description as descript4_0_1_, tasks0_.name as name5_0_1_, tasks0_.user_id as user_id6_0_1_ from tasks tasks0_ where tasks0_.user_id=?

Hibernate: select tasks0_.user_id as user_id6_1_0_, tasks0_.id as id1_0_0_, tasks0_.id as id1_0_1_, tasks0_.created_on as created_2_0_1_, tasks0_.deadline as deadline3_0_1_, tasks0_.description as descript4_0_1_, tasks0_.name as name5_0_1_, tasks0_.user_id as user_id6_0_1_ from tasks   tasks0_ where tasks0_.user_id=?
```

Comment: Do you have something that handle transactions for you ? Maybe it is setting the transaction to readonly in your case.

Comment: I am using the hibernate transaction manager, managed by spring. Maybe you're right, but why the create method works via webapp?

Comment: Someone may have written a config file to allow write operations only for methods whose name begins by "save" or "create".

Comment: I wrote the entire application from scratch, so no, i don't remember have written something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this delete method:

```
@Override
public void delete(Integer userId) {
    session.getCurrentSession().delete(get("id",userId));
    session.getCurrentSession().flush();
}
```

, maybe you just need to flush your active session to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

can you change your delete method and try out this?

```
private boolean deleteById(Class<?> type, Serializable id) {
Object persistentInstance = session.load(type, id);
if (persistentInstance != null) {
    session.delete(persistentInstance);
    return true;
}
return false;}
```

simply invoke by 
deleteById(User.class, id);

is there any child classes or 1tomany or many2many associations?

Comment: I changed it but, i still having the same issue, in fact, in my controller i tried this: `System.out.println("\n"+userService.delete(id)+"\n");` and that print `true`.
There is a 1 to many relationship between User and Task.

Comment: Can you enable hibernate logging and check what is coming up in logs

Comment: is there a delete cascade set on user to task on db or at java level?

Comment: Yes, `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
 private Collection<Task> tasks;`